# Widgets da área de trabalho em Java

Tags: java

Estou com uma ideia de criar um widgets com funcionalidade de suporte para minha empresa.

Gostaria de saber se via [java](/questions/tagged/java) eu conseguiria criar algo, se existe algum *framework* ou alguma tecnologia em Java em que possa criar algo do tipo.

Comment: Que funções de suporte este _widget_ teria?

Comment: @felipe.zkn Estou pensando em chamar um Janela do navegador com o chat do suporte, pois hoje já disponho de uma aplicação de suporte que roda no navegador. Ow se caso melhor redesenho a aplicação do suporte e direciono para a aplicação de suporte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das alternativas que você pode usar para fazer isso é o [**Google Web Toolkit**](http://www.gwtproject.org/).

> O Google Web Toolkit é um toolkit de código-fonte aberto permitindo a
>   desenvolvedores, criar aplicativos com tecnologia Ajax em linguagem de
>   programação Java. GWT suporta cliente-servidor, desenvolvimento e
>   debugging em qualquer IDE Java.

- [Tutoriais](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/) (em inglês)
- [Exemplos](http://www.gwtproject.org/examples.html)

Comment: Eu li "Widgets da área de trabalho" e a primeira coisa que me veio a cabeça foi desktop rs.

Answer (score 4):

> Estou com uma ideia de criar um widgets com funcionalidade de suporte para minha empresa.

Ok.

> Gostaria de saber se via java eu conseguiria criar algo

Sim

> se existe algum framework ou alguma tecnologia em Java em que possa criar algo do tipo.

Sim, existem. JavaFX, AWT e Swing, por exemplo.

Com o Swing e o AWT você pode criar uma instância da classe `java.awt.Window` e adicionar um ou mais `JComponent` nela, como em qualquer aplicação Swing. Ao instanciar a classe `java.awt.Window` diretamente, você obterá uma janela vazia, sem botão de fechar, bordas, barra de título ou qualquer outra coisa, o que é ideal para se trabalhar com objetos que ficam direto na área de trabalho como as suas notificações de chat. Você pode até fazer esta janela ter um fundo transparente se desejar.

Não entendo ainda de JavaFX, mas creio que deve ser possível com essa tecnologia também.

Comment: +1. JavaFX deveria ser a solução que mais se adequa a necessidade dele, já possui diversos componentes ricos e é de fácil aprendizado. Outra solução seria Swing + Flamingo Look and Feel (para visual rico).